# How do I set alignment on DataGridTextColumn cell text using code

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to add `DataGridTextColumn` programmatically, and set some properties to present the text in cells.
I don't want to use `TemplateColumn` as it requires double-tab to enter edit mode.
I can't find code that would set alignment of the text.
Anyone has any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

I tried so far:

```
Dim txt As New DataGridTextColumn()         
Dim c As New DataGridCell    
c.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center    
txt.CellStyle = c.Style
```

and

```
txt.SetValue(TextBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
```

and few others that I didn't keep track of.

Comment: Hi, I tried a few, these did not work:

Comment: This article covers how to create and apply styles in depth: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29699/WPF-How-to-create-Styles-in-code-and-magical-Conte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your help and I found the solution only with your guidance.
Especially thanks to @AnjumSKhan

This worked for me:

```
    Dim txt As New DataGridTextColumn()
    Dim s As New Style
    s.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right))
    txt.CellStyle = s
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a style, and then assign it to txt.CellStyle.

C# code :

```
Style s = new Style();
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
txt.CellStyle = s;
```

Comment: Hi AnjumSKhan, I translated it into vb.net and it created a textblock in the middle of the cell, and if you got into the textblock it would expand as you add the text. But if you click anywhere around the narrow string of cellblock (before I add text) then nothing happens.

Comment: @murmyl Hi, u can also try : `DataGridCell.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty`

Answer (score 0):

In your c# code you have to use the index of the column. Here are some examples to set the cell alignment:

```
    dataGrid.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    dataGrid.Columns[0].ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
```

Comment: I'm using vb.net which I'm usually able to translate from c#, but I cannot find ItemStyle property in column properties.

Comment: grd.Columns(0).CellStyle = TextAlignment.Center

Comment: Hi Gregg, thanks for this but this does not work. the part 'TextAlignment.Center' is underlined as error. Did you use any Imports etc?